# React marking which page i'm on

Tags: reactjs, class, paging, classname

I'd like for my app to indicate which page I'm currently on. Page numbers get calculated based on the length of an array, and when I move between them, the current page would have a different background. The current page is saved inside the state as well as in local storage.

So I have a CSS class .mark-page {background-color} and I thought I'd just make a ternary inside the button, but it didn't work, however, I'm not sure which parameters to input. Any ideas?

```
const pageNumbers = [];
for (let i = 1; i <= Math.ceil(allFacts.length / factsPerPage); i++) {
  pageNumbers.push(i);
}

const renderPageNumbers = pageNumbers.map((number) => {
  return (
    <button key={number} id={number} onClick={this.handleClick}>
      {number}
    </button>
  );
});

return <div id="paging">{renderPageNumbers}</div>;
```

Comment: Can you provide the complete code you've implemented relevant to the above module ?

Comment: @KavinduVIndika hey, posted the code below :)

Answer (score 0):

@KavinduVindika sure, posting here because it won't let me edit my post:

```
    class Body extends React.Component {
    constructor() {
        super()
        this.state = {
            isLoading: true,
            allFacts: [],
            currentPage: null,
            factsPerPage: 15,
            error: null,
        }
        this.handleClick = this.handleClick.bind(this)
        }

        componentDidMount() {
        gets API, saves it into state and sets currentPage to 1 if the page had just 
        loaded }

        handleClick(event) {
        
        this.setState ({
            currentPage: localStorage.getItem("currentPage")
        })
        let currentPage = Number(event.target.id)
        localStorage.setItem("currentPage", JSON.stringify(currentPage))
        this.setState ({currentPage: currentPage})
    }

    render() {
        const {allFacts, currentPage, factsPerPage } = this.state
        const indexOfLastFact = currentPage * factsPerPage
        const indexOfFirstFact = indexOfLastFact - factsPerPage
        const allFactsSliced = allFacts.slice(indexOfFirstFact, indexOfLastFact)
        console.log(allFactsSliced)

        const renderAllFacts = this.state.isLoading ? 
        <div id="loading"><h3 className="fact-div" >Please wait.<br/> The cats are disclosing their secrets.</h3></div> :
        allFactsSliced.map((fact, index) => { 
            return <div className="fact-div" key={index}>
            <p className="fact-num">Fact # {(index+1) + (currentPage-1) * factsPerPage}:</p>
            <p className="fact-txt">{fact.fact}</p>
            </div>
        })
```

hope this is all the important bits